# R Package: How to link function using Source()

Tags: r, shiny, r-package

So I have an R package that uses a Shiny Application. I want the server.R to use another file as a source. Here's my directory:

```
PackageName:
     inst:
          ShinyApp:
              server.R
              ui.R
      R:
           myFunction1.R
           myFunction2.R
           myConstructor.R
```

I want the `server.R` to use the `myConstructor.R` as a source to call interactively. But How can I do so? I've tried `source(PackageName::R::("myConstructor.R"))`, `source(PackageName::("myConstructor.R"))`, `source(system.file("R", package="PackageName"), "myConstructor.R")` at the top of the `server.R` file but these all did not work. Any Help?

Comment: does `source("../../R/myConstructor.R")` work? This might be a good use of the `here` [librarry](https://github.com/r-lib/here)

Comment: @Nate that package failed to download due to another package that cannot be removed called 'backports'. and no that did not work, with source("PackageName/R/myConstructor.R")